# Date-time field within tables

Tags: datetime, table-field

I'm after using a date-time field within a table cell. I suspect it requires a plugin to make this happen - has anyone done this?

Comment: I started making such a plugin (copied lots of code from default table field type), but it's not complete. Though basic functionality works already. I can push a repo soon, if you want.

Comment: Yes please. Would be great if you could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding more cell types to the Table Fields isn't possible without a plugin. Even with a plugin it's probably not possible to simply extend the default field. I tried to do this and couldn't find a way to extend upon the javascript necessary to add or delete rows.

So to make more cell types possible I ended up copying the complete Table Field code from Craft core into my plugin.

["Event Table"](https://github.com/carlcs/craft-eventtable)

Someone might ask what this is good for, you could use Matrix instead!
Sure, but sometimes you're in the need for another hierarchy level or you'd simply opt for the cleaner, more compact view of a table field for your date or time inputs.